# Camunda: Main Class for handling of passing variables between processes and sub processes

Tags: spring-boot, camunda

I am working on Camunda project with spring boot framework. In project we use Cumunda's processes and sub processes. At the moment for passing the variables between processes and sub process is used code bellow in bpmn files.

Is there a solution which uses main class which would handle all possible processes and sub processes and passing variables between them in that way that I can remove code below from bpmn files and to save me time in upcoming work like adding new Camunda processes/subprocesses.

```
 <bpmn:extensionElements>
    <camunda:in variables="all" />
    <camunda:out variables="all" />
 </bpmn:extensionElements>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could write a https://docs.camunda.org/manual/latest/user-guide/process-engine/process-engine-plugins/ that implements a ParseListener to add this configuration on the fly to all your processes. An example for a ParseListener in general is available here: https://github.com/camunda/camunda-bpm-examples/tree/master/process-engine-plugin/bpmn-parse-listener

However, I would probably not do this, as it adds some complexity all developers need to understand, whereas the normal property is standard and not much work to add to the process models.